"TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float32' has no len()" - DeepSORT Integration with YOLO
I'm integrating YOLOv8 with DeepSORT for multi-object tracking, but I'm encountering a TypeError when passing detection data to the DeepSORT update_tracks() function.
Error Message:

Speed: 4.5ms preprocess, 332.2ms inference, 0.6ms postprocess per
image at shape (1, 3, 480, 640) Detections for DeepSORT: [[     107.22
186.92      639.26      479.49     0.83611]] Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/roy/environments/001-opencv/004-opencv.py",
line 127, in  detect_customers() File
"/home/roy/environments/001-opencv/004-opencv.py", line 84, in
detect_customers tracks = tracker.update_tracks(deep_sort_detections,
frame=frame) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File
"/home/roy/environments/001-opencv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/deep_sort_realtime/deepsort_tracker.py",
line 195, in update_tracks assert len(raw_detections[0][0])==4
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float32'
has no len()

Code Section (Detection and Tracking):
def detect_customers():
    # Initialize YOLO and DeepSORT
    model = YOLO("yolov8s.pt")  # Load YOLO model
    tracker = DeepSort(max_age=30, n_init=3)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Replace 0 with the video source
    active_customers = {}

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        results = model(frame)  # Perform YOLO inference
        detections = []

        for result in results:
            for box in result.boxes:
                # Extract bounding box and confidence score
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0].tolist()  # Convert bounding box to list
                confidence = float(box.conf[0])  # Confidence score
                
                # Append detection in the required format
                detection = [float(x1), float(y1), float(x2), float(y2), float(confidence)]
                detections.append(detection)

        # Handle empty detections
        if len(detections) == 0:
            deep_sort_detections = np.empty((0, 5))  # Empty array for no detections
        else:
            deep_sort_detections = np.array(detections, dtype=np.float32)  # Convert to NumPy array with proper structure

        # Debugging: Print the detections being passed to DeepSORT
        print("Detections for DeepSORT:", deep_sort_detections)

        # Update tracker
        tracks = tracker.update_tracks(deep_sort_detections, frame=frame)
        for track in tracks:
            if not track.is_confirmed():
                continue

            track_id = track.track_id
            ltrb = track.to_ltrb()  # Convert to (left, top, right, bottom)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(ltrb[0]), int(ltrb[1])), (int(ltrb[2]), int(ltrb[3])), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, f"ID: {track_id}", (int(ltrb[0]), int(ltrb[1]) - 10),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # Display frame
        cv2.imshow("Customer Detection", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:  # Press ESC to exit
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Problem Summary:

Error Description: When passing the deep_sort_detections to
tracker.update_tracks(), I get the TypeError: object of type
'numpy.float32' has no len().
Detections Format: I’m formatting    detections as [[x1, y1, x2, y2,
confidence], ...] and converting it    to a NumPy array with
dtype=np.float32. However, it seems like    DeepSORT expects a
different format or there is some type issue.

Question:

How can I properly format the detection data to be compatible with
DeepSORT's update_tracks() method?
Am I missing something in the way    the data should be structured or
passed to DeepSORT?


please refrain from running your question through ChatGPT


TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float32' has no len()

The problem can be fixed.
Replace
if len(detections) == 0:
with:
if detections:

Output:
0: 480x640 1 person, 2181.0ms Speed: 43.0ms preprocess, 2181.0ms inference, 8.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 480, 640) Detections for DeepSORT: []
0: 480x640 1 person, 2013.0ms Speed: 10.0ms preprocess, 2013.0ms inference, 6.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 480, 640) Detections for DeepSORT: []
0: 480x640 1 person, 1983.0ms Speed: 7.0ms preprocess, 1983.0ms inference, 7.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 480, 640) Detections for DeepSORT: []
0: 480x640 1 person, 2005.0ms Speed: 6.0ms preprocess, 2005.0ms inference, 6.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 480, 640) Detections for DeepSORT: []
0: 480x640 1 person, 1972.0ms Speed: 7.0ms preprocess, 1972.0ms inference, 6.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 480, 640) Detections for DeepSORT: []
